# Transimpedance amplifier circuit not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am making a trans-impedance amplifier using [AD549](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD549.pdf) op amp that simulates a current-to-voltage conversion on a satellite radiation detector. In my circuit, an ultra-high value resistor (10G) is placed in series with an input voltage to create an input current. The feedback resistor is also equal to 10G and is part of the overall TIA structure.

The output voltage should be equal to an input voltage (plus a little offset due to the bias current); so if the input is equal to 1V then the output voltage should be 1V plus some mV. But for some reason, the output stays at 2.8 V regardless of the input voltage range. I tried removing one resistor at a time from the circuit, but the output is still 2.8V.

[image]

Can somebody spot where the error is? I would really appreciate it!
Below is the schematic:
[image]

Comment: Could you add a schematic so we don't have to reverse engineer from your picture? There is a schematic editing tool when you open the edit window for your question.

Comment: please link the datasheet..I can't find a "AD659" on the internet.

Comment: AD659 is a typo, I guess for [AD549](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad549.html). Is the inverting input connected to common, and non-inverting input to ground? Then indeed "The output voltage should be equal to an input voltage" but within sign. What's V+ and V- ? Are the customary 100nF power supply decoupling capacitors to ground missing, or soldered under the IC so we can't see them?

Comment: Love those resistors! I suspect the double sided tape below the breadboard isn't rated in the teraOhms...

Answer (score 1):

With 5 GOhm impedance at the inverting input, stray radiation will couple strongly into it and cause haywire output voltage.. Especially with this loose wiring. You need shielding.

You likely need a couple pF feedback capacitance to damp oscillation.

Comment: I feel like the fact that it's all built on a breadboard is a bigger concern, with such enormous impedances. There's already a couple pF between every node on the circuit.